# Using loop command in batch files to perform netuse

Tags: windows, batch-file

i trying to figure if there's a faster way to do the commands stated below, maybe using a loop.

```
net use \\xx.xx.x.51 password /user:userid
net use \\xx.xx.x.52 password /user:userid
net use \\xx.xx.x.53 password /user:userid
net use \\xx.xx.x.54 password /user:userid
net use \\xx.xx.x.55 password /user:userid
net use \\xx.xx.x.56 password /user:userid
net use \\xx.xx.x.57 password /user:userid
net use \\xx.xx.x.58 password /user:userid
net use \\xx.xx.x.59 password /user:userid
```

Comment: `for /l %# in (51 1 59) do net use \\xx.xx.x.%# password /user:userid`. If you're using a .bat instead of cmd, `%%#`.